# O que a seguinte linha em R faz?

Tags: r

Estou com dúvida quanto a seguinte linha:

```
 amostra = sample(2,40,replace = T,prob=c(0.7,0.3))?
```

Em especial o argumento `2`, o argumento `40` e o `replace`.

Comment: Já leu a [documentação](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/sample) desta função?

Answer (score 5):

A sintaxe do jeito que está é um pouco estranha mesmo.

Como descrito na documentação, o primeiro argumento pode ser um vetor, do qual você deseja tirar uma mostra ou um número inteiro. Se for um número inteiro, ela vai fazer uma amostra de 1 até esse número. No caso, como é um número inteiro (2), a função irá fazer uma amostra do vetor `c(1,2)`.

`40`, o segundo argumento (`n`), é o tamanho da amostra que você deseja retirar. Ou seja, essa chamada da função `sample` irá retornar um vetor com `40` elementos.

`replace` é um argumento se indica se a amostra será feita com ou sem reposição. No caso, como você vai fazer uma amostra de tamanho 40 de um vetor de tamanho 2, ele é obrigatoriamente com reposição (`replace = TRUE`).

Por último, o argumento `prob` permite que você especifique probabilidades para sortear cada um dos elementos do vetor que você está amostrando. No caso, `c(0.7, 0.3)` indica que na chamada dessa função você irá 1 com 70% de probabilidade e 2 com 30%.

Para resumir: Essa linha retorna uma amostra aleatória com reposição de tamanho 40 dos elementos do vetor `c(1,2)` sendo que 1 tem probabilidade 70% e 2, 30%.

---

No `R`, em geral a documentação é razoavelmente boa. Vale a pena ler o help das funções. Dentro do próprio R, se você digitar `help(sample)`, aparecerá uma janela com a documentação.